# Creation of Wifi Connection With Native Wifi API

Tags: c#, wifi

How can I establish wifi connection with Native Wifi API?
How can I share internet via established wifi in C#? I try to use [Managed Wifi API](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/) and with that I can connect to an existing wifi but I couldn't create new one.